# AngularJS: Can I use a filter to chunk an array in ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**Edit to add a clear question:** I have a flat array of some length and I want to put it into a tr/td type view? This might also be in a bootstrap grid or something like that. Essentially I want to display a flat array in a series of length-n chunks.

There are a number of variations of this question on SO but I haven't really seen a good explanation of either: how to make this work or why it can't. So I've made an extremely [simple example](https://github.com/lyda/angularjs-chunk-filter) that demonstrates the problem. It will render, but if you check the logs you'll see errors (which are too large to link to).

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US" ng-app="rowApp">
<head><title>Angular chunks</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular.min.js" integrity="sha384-c4XWi4+MS7dBmCkPfB02+p/ExOF/ZBOfD2S4KR6mkmpBOg7IM6SUpA1KYZaVr7qE" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <table ng-controller="rowController" border="1" style="width:30%">
    <tr ng-repeat="people_chunk in people | chunk:4">
      <td ng-repeat="person in people_chunk">{{person.name}}</td>
    </td>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

app.js:

```
var rowApp = angular.module('rowApp', ['filters']);

angular.module('filters', []).
  filter('chunk', function () {
    return function (items, chunk_size) {
      var chunks = [];
      if (angular.isArray(items)) {
        if (isNaN(chunk_size))
          chunk_size = 4;
        for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i += chunk_size) {
          chunks.push(items.slice(i, i + chunk_size));
        }
      } else {
        console.log("items is not an array: " + angular.toJson(items));
      }
      return chunks;
    };
});

rowApp.controller('rowController',
  function ($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("/people.json")
      .then(function(response) { $scope.people = response.data; });
});
```

people.json:

```
[{"name": "a"}, {"name": "b"}, {"name": "c"}, {"name": "d"},
 {"name": "1"}, {"name": "2"}, {"name": "3"}, {"name": "4"}]
```

You can then serve all this with `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 9000` and then go to `http://localhost:9000/`

Comment: Do you want to split an array in 4, and ng-repeat over them?

Comment: Really not clear what your objective is.

Comment: The error messages that you're getting, are probably because of an infinite loop. You can see if you use breakpoints, that your filter is executed till angular kills it.

Comment: @K.Gkinis OK, that seems possible. But I'm not clear why. (I put an explicit questionat the start)

Comment: I think this is presentation specific logic, should be accomplished using CSS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can avoid an infinite digest loop by simply memoizing your chunk function.  This solves the issue of ng-repeat never finding the proper references and always thinking you are returning new items causing the infinite $digest.

```
angular.module('filters', []).
  filter('chunk', function () {
​
    function cacheIt(func) {
      var cache = {};
      return function(arg, chunk_size) {
        // if the function has been called with the argument
        // short circuit and use cached value, otherwise call the
        // cached function with the argument and save it to the cache as well then return
        return cache[arg] ? cache[arg] : cache[arg] = func(arg,chunk_size);
      };
    }
    
    // unchanged from your example apart from we are no longer directly returning this   ​
    function chunk(items, chunk_size) {
      var chunks = [];
      if (angular.isArray(items)) {
        if (isNaN(chunk_size))
          chunk_size = 4;
        for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i += chunk_size) {
          chunks.push(items.slice(i, i + chunk_size));
        }
      } else {
        console.log("items is not an array: " + angular.toJson(items));
      }
      return chunks;
    }
​    // now we return the cached or memoized version of our chunk function
    // if you want to use lodash this is really easy since there is already a chunk and memoize function all above code would be removed
    // this return would simply be: return _.memoize(_.chunk);

    return cacheIt(chunk);
  });
```

Comment: Interesting. I saw a similar answer but it assumed you had lodash which I don't just yet. Made an so-answer-2 branch with this in it. One question: could the angular cache work here?

Comment: its seem to not passing the chunk_size correctly to chunk method. Also caching is based on array being first argument, not a best way to set a property name, I think.

Comment: it works, but changed `cache = {};` to `var cache = {}` because of global scope garbage.

Answer (score 2):

As the filter is returning new array instances as slices, angular's `ngRepeat` will detect them changed (as `ngRepeat` uses `$watchCollection` internally), and will cause and infinite digest loop. There is even an issue about that, but it is abandoned since 2013: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/2033

This issue still persists if you change the snippet to contain a non-constant expression, like `[[x]]`:

```
<div ng-repeat="a in [[x]]">
  <div ng-repeat="b in a">
  </div>
</div>
```

I am afraid you will have to move the chunking logic into the controller, or to use css to form a 4-width table.

Comment: Ah. And this is why another similar question had a "memoize" call...

OK. Thanks.

Would rather not have it in the controller, but that is where I eventually put it. Now at least I know why it has to be there.

Thanks!

Comment: You should move the chunking logic to a service imho. (but this is a correct answer :) )

Answer (score 0):

maybe this could work to someone, you never know
the following code will assign an extra value (store_chunk) to an array of stores. so I can use with ng-repeat to show 3 different columns in my HTML

```
        var x               = 0;
        var y               = 1;
        var how_many_chunks = 3;
        var limit = $scope.main.stores.length / how_many_chunks ;
        angular.forEach($scope.main.stores, function(e, key) {
            if (x <= limit) {
                $scope.main.stores[key].store_chunk = y;
            }
            else{
                y    += 1;
                limit = y * limit;
                $scope.main.stores[key].store_chunk = y;
            }
            x += 1;
        });
```

here the HTML

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
        <ul class="main_report">
            <li ng-repeat="store in main.stores | filter:{ store_chunk: 3 }">{{store.store_name}}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
        <ul class="main_report">
            <li ng-repeat="store in main.stores | filter:{ store_chunk: 3 }">{{store.store_name}}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
        <ul class="main_report">
            <li ng-repeat="store in main.stores | filter:{ store_chunk: 3 }">{{store.store_name}}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

this works like a charm! and don't vote down just because you didn't like it!.. thumbs up instead!